# How to pass Pagination object in HTTP Get method in angular 4 for fetching data from REST API using spring boot

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

This is my code segment for fetching data from REST using angular HTTP, I can not pass any body inside the request.

```
this.http.get('paymentadvicelist').map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
})
```

Comment: If you are using GET method for call then you can pass your data using query params in URL and if you want to pass data as body then change your method type to POST

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this by using GET method only?.

Comment: No . GET method in webservices do not accept body. But talking about alternative way then you can pass data in headers of GET webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type your "http" member is.

If you use the (newer) `HttpClient` API then you can use the [`httpClient.request()` method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) (like `httpClient.request("GET", url, {body: theRequestBody})`.

If you use the older `Http` class (which is deprecated since angular 4.3) then you can set the request body in the request options, see the API documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#get).